# What is calcined lawsonite?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, minerals, geochemistry, ceramics

For context, I am planning to try and use this sample to make a ceramic glaze.

I recently collected a sample of what I think is lawsonite, which has the chemical formula $\ce{CaAl_2Si_2O7(OH)_2*H_2O}$. After collecting it I calcined it in an electric (oxidation) kiln to around 2016 °F. Assuming that what I collected is indeed lawsonite, what happened to it? I'm assuming that all the water "evaporated", leaving some combination of $\ce{CaO},\,\ce{Al_2O_3},$ and $\ce{SiO_2}$.

Comment: It probably decomposed.

Comment: @NilayGhosh what does that mean?

Comment: It means lawsonite decomposed at high temp, leaving behind compounds you mentioned:  CaO, Al2O3 and SiO2. The water present as water of crystallization  evaporated.

Comment: @NilayGhosh Okay so we have $$\ce{CaAl2Si2O7(OH)2*H2O}=\ce{CaO}+\ce{Al2O3}+2\ce{SiO2}+2\ce{H2O}$$ so I guess $$\ce{CaAl2Si2O7(OH)2*H2O}+\text{heat(2016 °F)}\to \ce{CaO}+\ce{Al2O3}+2\ce{SiO2}.$$
Does that sound accurate?

Comment: Yes. $\ce{~~}$.